# Primary key error in inserting rows into a view SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a new view, based on an existing table.  I want this new view to have inserted records.

Here's the original table, called `population`:

```
Agency    Year    Total   PopGroup
01        2017    3467    3C
01        2018    3444    3C
01        2019    3567    3C
02        2017    1000    1C
02        2018    1354    1C
02        2019    1333    1C
03        2017    6784    2C
03        2018    3453    2C
04        2017    3333    2C
```

If an agency has a row for year 2019, I want to duplicate this row and call it 2020 (basically, an estimate population for 2020). Here's the desired result for my view:

```
Agency    Year    Total   PopGroup
01        2017    3467    3C
01        2018    3444    3C
01        2019    3567    3C
01        2020    3567    3C
02        2017    1000    1C
02        2018    1354    1C
02        2019    1333    1C
02        2020    1333    1C
03        2017    6784    2C
03        2018    3453    2C
04        2017    3333    2C
```

This is my code to try and create the view:

```
Use MY_PROJECTS
Go

CREATE VIEW population_w2020Estimates AS
SELECT *
FROM [MY_PROJECTS].[dbo].[population]
WHERE Year in (2017,2018,2019)

GO

INSERT INTO population_w2020Estimates (Agency, Year, Total, PopGroup)
SELECT Agency, 2020 as Year, Total, PopGroup
FROM population_w2020Estimates
```

The view is created, but the insert fails, with the following error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object...
```

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: What is your primary key in your population table??

Comment: Agency and Year.

Comment: But since I am changing "2019" to "2020", I'm not duplicating the primary key... why the error?

Comment: I think you might have a misunderstanding: inserting into a view inserts actually inserts into the base table. If the view filters out the row, it is possible to insert but not see the row afterwards in the view

Comment: Why is this?  Why does inserting into a view inserts into the base table?  I did not know this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want your view to show you an extra row for each agency as 2020 data derived from 2019 data then create the view as below:

```
CREATE VIEW population_w2020Estimates AS
SELECT *
FROM [population]
WHERE Year in (2017,2018,2019)
union all
SELECT Agency, 2020 as Year, Total, PopGroup
FROM population where year='2019'
```

Comment: Something is wrong.  It's inserting those records into population table, not the view.

Comment: It will insert the data in population table not in view. Do you want this to be in view only?

Comment: Yes, only the view. Aren't I changing the structure of the original table, which is not good?   I don't want to mess with the structure of the original table.. I only want it in the view.  Is this possible?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I have modified my answer. What you need is to create a view with extra rows for 2020.

Comment: Thanks.  Will this edited answer affect anything in the original population table?   It's not my table to change.. so I want to make sure nothing is changed there.

Comment: No. There will be no impact on the table. It will just create a view with all the data from the table and extra rows for agency wise 2020 data for which agencies rows exist for 2019.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new row with 2020 for every current row in the `population_w2020Estimates` view. So for Agency `01` the `SELECT` will bring back three rows - 2017,2018,2019. Hence the primary key error. Try:

```
INSERT INTO population_w2020Estimates (Agency, Year, Total, PopGroup)
SELECT Agency, 2020 as Year, Total, PopGroup
FROM population_w2020Estimates
WHERE Year = 2019
```

Comment: Unfortunately, still getting an error and not sure why.  Primary key error at 01, 2020

Comment: Or, rather, "The duplicate key value is (01, 2020)."  But how can that be when 2020 did not exist prior to the insert?

Comment: Your view only includes 2017,2018 and 2019 data from `population`. Are you sure that `population` does not contain rows for 2020 already? Bear in mind that you are not inserting into the view, but rather into the underlying table.

Comment: Yes, positive.  It doesn't contain 2020.

Comment: weird, putting in 9999 instead of 2020 works.  hmm.

Comment: Do you not have access to the underlying table? What does `SELECT * FROM population WHERE Year = 2020` bring back?

Comment: Please just try select * from population where year=2020; just be sure.